# Jquery switch between 2 colors by css class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need switches between 2 icons (in this example colors) by css class on element if i click on it. I have this code (which is not working):

```js
$( ".play" ).on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();


    $(this).removeClass('play');
    $(this).addClass('stop');

    console.log('play');
});

$( ".stop" ).on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();


    alert();

    $(this).removeClass('stop');
    $(this).addClass('play');

    console.log('stop');
});
```

```css
.play {
    background-color: black;
}

.stop {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="play" style="width:100px; height: 100px; display: block;"></a>
```

Comment: Why don't use toggleClass() ?

Comment: I was tryied toggleClass() but event was't triggered too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using Event Delegation with jQuery, but I think you might have it a little wrong:

```
$("body")
    .on("click", ".play", function(event) {
        // change "play" to "stop"
    })
    .on("click", ".stop", function(event) {
        // change "stop" to "play"
    });
```

You want to attach the `click` handler to the `<body>` tag, and then provide jQuery with the event name, CSS selector, and event handler.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2):

```js
$( "a" ).on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var anchor = $(this);

    if(anchor.hasClass('play'))
    {
        $(this).removeClass('play');
        $(this).addClass('stop');

        console.log('play');
    }
    else
    {
    alert();

    $(this).removeClass('stop');
    $(this).addClass('play');

    }
});
```

```css
.play {
    background-color: black;
}

.stop {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="play" style="width:100px; height: 100px; display: block;"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't bind the event handlers to a class, bind it to the id of your element. Then you can just see what class the element has and switch between them.

[Here is a working codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/VvYmyg)

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="clickable" class="play" style="width:100px; height: 100px; display: block;"></a>
```

CSS: Doesn't change

JS:

```
$( "#clickable" ).on('click', function(event) {
  if($(this).hasClass('play')) {
    $(this).removeClass('play');
    $(this).addClass('stop');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('stop');
    $(this).addClass('play');
  }
});
```

Comment: `.play` is available and perfectly fine, no need for an id. You should rather mention that the problem comes from the fact that there is no `.stop` at the time he tries to bind the click event :-P I like your solution though, more than the chosen one, no need for event delegation here.

Answer (score 0):

As easy as.....

```js
$( "a" ).on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('stop');
    $(this).toggleClass('play');
});
```

```css
.play {
    background-color: black;
}

.stop {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="play" style="width:100px; height: 100px; display: block;"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also do this:-
css:

```
    .play {
        background-color: black;
    }

    .stop {
        background-color: green;
    }
```

JS:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".play").on('click', function(event) {
            if ($('a').hasClass('stop')) {
                $(".play").addClass("play").removeClass("stop");
            } else {
                $(".play").addClass("stop");
            }
            console.log('play');
        });
    });
</script>
```

```
<a href="#" class="play" style="width:100px; height: 100px; display: block;"></a>
```

html and css remain the same.